# scraping website with javascript cookie with c#

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to scrape some things from the following site: http://www.conrad.nl/modelspoor.

This is my function:

```
public string SreenScrape(string urlBase, string urlPath)
{
    CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlBase + urlPath);
    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 7.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.9 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
    WebResponse webResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    string result = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd();
    webResponse.Close();

    if (result.Contains("<frame src="))
    {
        Regex metaregex = new Regex("http:[a-z:/._0-9!?=A-Z&]*",RegexOptions.Multiline);
        result = result.Replace("\r\n", "");
        Match m = metaregex.Match(result);
        string key = m.Groups[0].Value;

        foreach (Match match in metaregex.Matches(result))
        {
            HttpWebRequest redirectHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(key);
            redirectHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
            webResponse = redirectHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            string redirectResponse = new System.IO.StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd();
            webResponse.Close();
            return redirectResponse;
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

But when i do this i get a string with an error from the website that it use javascript.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Noticed you don't set redirectHttpWebRequest.UserAgent as you do for httpWebRequest for the main request. Maybe it causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using the article on my blog ([Use C# to Scrape web pages](http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=111)) I was able to get the page. Here is the code:

```
string target            = @"http://www1.conrad.nl/modelspoor/";
HttpWebRequest request   = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( target );
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using ( Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream() )
    using ( StreamReader htmlStream = new StreamReader( responseStream, Encoding.UTF8 ) )
        Console.WriteLine( htmlStream.ReadToEnd() );
```

HTH

Comment: Hi,

Sorry i was forgotten to tel that i get from the first page the html. I has a frame index.

When i go to the frame link i get the error about the javascript or that there can't be created a shopchart.

I want the menu items in from the middle screen on the bottom.

Comment: did you have an idea how to fix it?